# Custom sound remote push notification iOS not working

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to change the sound of the remote message

I've added the file into my project, see picture 1

[image: Structure application]

I've also added everything into my AppDelegate. In the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I've added:

```
 if (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue >= 8.0 {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Sound | .Alert | .Badge, categories: nil))
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Badge | .Sound | .Alert)
    }

    //Clear badge
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

The other methods I've implemented are:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.hexString
    println(deviceTokenString)
    let task = service.writeForNotifications(token: deviceTokenString, completionHandler: {
    })
    task.resume()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    println("Failed to get token: \(error)")
}
```

The Json I received from the service is:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"The push message!", "sound":"ice.caf"}}
```

I'm not sure whitch step I've forgotten to change the sound of the notification?
When I receive a notification it always plays the default sound.

Comment: please check that "ice.caf" is actually in the resulting "ipa" file. It is possible it has been added to the project but it was not added to your build. Or the format is invalid. Try it with a "wav" file, for example.

Comment: Yes, this was my problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, There is a problem with IOS  8.3 or latest, its will work on IOS 7. It could be a bug probably.

Comment: @cyberlobe you have to pass it with your push notification. iOS handles it automatically when you set up your push notification correctly. See the json I received from the service.

Comment: @HannesVandenBerghe its done, Actually issues was in PHP script. There was still an default Sound added. I changed it to custom sound name & it worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure the file is added to the bundle? You can check this by looking at the `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phases`.

See this image for clarification:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to check the following thing to push notification work

- The sound file should not be greater then 30 seconds
- The sound file should be valid format, ( .aiff, .wav or .caf file ) some time extension of the file show it is right but it is not, so you need to convert it
- The sound file should be at the root folder of your project not in sub folder
- The pay load (push json data) should be in correct format (in your case it look good)
- The push notification should be `on` in the `Capabilities` of you project setting (in your case it looks `on` because you are getting notification with default sound)
- Please make sure that your sound file is listed in the `Copy Bundle Resources` in the `Build Phases`

Comment: I had a 31-sec .wav file that worked fine on iPhone 11 Pro but was silent on iPhone 11. I cut it to 28 seconds (just in case) and now it works on every iPhone.

Comment: How do you make sure you sound file is listend in the Copy Bundle Resources?