# How to play a custom ringtone on new firebase message(pushed notification) when app is in background for IOS?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

App runs correctly on android(notification is pushed and the device starts ringing), but on IOS, **app receives notification but ringtone starts after opening the app again...**

I have capabilities set too, background modes(audio background fetch, remote notifications, and background proccessing) and push notifications

I'm trying to play a custom sound in onMessage method...

**Firebase listener**

```
void firebaseCloudMessagingListeners(BuildContext context) {
    final deliveryCubit = BlocProvider.of<DeliveryCubit>(context);
    final playerService = PlayerService();

    if (Platform.isIOS) getIOSPermission();

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
           debugPrint('FMC -> $message');
           if(appInBackground){
           playerService.playRingtone();
         }
       
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        debugPrint('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

        debugPrint('on launch $message');
      },
    );
  }
```

**Player service**

```
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;

class PlayerService {
  static PlayerService _instance;
  final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();

  factory PlayerService() => _instance ?? PlayerService._internal();

  PlayerService._internal(){
    _instance = this;
  }

  void playRingtone(){
    assetsAudioPlayer.open(
    Audio("assets/audios/iosRingtone.mp3"),
      showNotification: false,
  );
    assetsAudioPlayer.play();
  }

  void pauseRingtone(){
    assetsAudioPlayer.pause();
  }
}
```

And I try to stop the player on lifeCycleStateChange...

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch(state){
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        socketService.appInBackground = false;
        firebaseService.appInBackground = false;
        playerService.pauseRingtone();
        setState(() {
          appLifecycleState = AppLifecycleState.resumed;
        });
        print("LifecycleState resumed");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print("LifecycleState inactive");
        socketService.appInBackground = true;
        firebaseService.appInBackground = true;
        setState(() {
          appLifecycleState = AppLifecycleState.inactive;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        socketService.appInBackground = true;
        firebaseService.appInBackground = true;
        print("LifecycleState paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        print("LifecycleState detached");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: does app push notification payload contains custom alert sound settings ?

Comment: No, there are no configured alert sound settings for push notification payload...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
   “aps” : {
      “badge” : 9
      “sound” : “bingbong.aiff”
   },
   “messageID” : “ABCDEFGHIJ”
}
```

This is required in push notification payload to play sound. Also make sure you have asked permission to for alert and sound as well for push notifications.
The same file name should be present in your app bundle. You don't need to parse anything.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification

Comment: If it helped. Please select my answer it helps me to stay active here and help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom notification sound for firebase push notifications.

kind of duplicate of [Custom sound remote push notification iOS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346054/custom-sound-remote-push-notification-ios-not-working)

Go check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54104535/13375401 out, it works...